# No such directory while using a variable string in url (PHP)

Tags: php

Well, the title is probably not very helpful. I'm not sure how to describe this error. I'm sure it's caused by something stupid on my part. For the life of me though, I can't figure it out.

Here's what I'm trying to do: There's a list of folders in my directory "img/gallery"

Within each of those folders are images

There's also a folder called "img/thumbs" which is structured exactly the same but with thumbnail images

I am writing a script that does two things: it displays the names of the folders within "img/gallery" and displays a list of thumbnails with links to the images in that folder.

These two components, when run separately, work fine. Put together, I get an error at

`if ($handle = opendir('img/gallery/$file/'))`

saying that $file is not a valid directory.

Here's the code:

`

```
if ($handle = opendir('img/gallery/')) {
$blacklist = array('.', '..', 'somedir', 'somefile.php');
while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
    if (!in_array($file, $blacklist)) {
        echo "<h2>$file</h2>\n";
    }
}
closedir($handle);
}

echo "<P class='gallery'>\n";


if ($handle = opendir('img/gallery/$file/')) {
    while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
        if ($entry != "." && $entry != "..") {
            echo "<a class='fancybox' href='img/gallery/$file/$entry' data-fancybox-group='gallery'>\n<img src='img/thumbs/$file/$entry' alt='' /></a>\n";
        }
    }

    echo "</p>\n";

    closedir($handle);
}
```

`

And advice would be wonderfully helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Try it this way: `if ($handle = opendir("img/gallery/$file/"))`
A common problem is that the normal quotes ' ' will not display the variables so it will just search for a directory named $file which it will obviously not find.

Comment: PHP has a cool directory iterator thing you might want to use: http://php.net/manual/en/class.directoryiterator.php

Comment: `-1` for a basic PHP error that Google could fix.

Comment: *cries* Frederick, you're breaking my heart.

There is still a problem. It may be a simple fix. When the script runs, the output directory excludes $file and just gives me the subfolder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try quotes for variables? I always quote out my variables, just good practice.

```
if ($handle = opendir('img/gallery/')) {
$blacklist = array('.', '..', 'somedir', 'somefile.php');
while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
    if (!in_array($file, $blacklist)) {
        echo "<h2>$file</h2>\n";
    }
}
closedir($handle);
}

echo "<P class='gallery'>\n";


if ($handle = opendir('img/gallery/' . $file . '/')) {
    while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
        if ($entry != "." && $entry != "..") {
            echo "<a class='fancybox' href='img/gallery/" . $file . "/" . $entry . "' data-fancybox-group='gallery'>\n<img src='img/thumbs/" . $file . "/" . $entry . "' alt='' /></a>\n";
        }
    }

    echo "</p>\n";

    closedir($handle);
}
```

Comment: This solves the error, but now there's another issue: the variable $file does not work after I run the code. Here's what outputs:

<h2>burt residence</h2>
<P class='gallery'>
<a class='fancybox' href='img/gallery//burt residence' data-fancybox-group='gallery'>
<img src='img/thumbs//burt residence' alt='' /></a>
</p>

Comment: @JaredSteffen surely you need to nest the second while loop in the first so that you can get each image ($entry) in each folder ($file)?

Answer (score 1):

opendir should return true or false but it may not be playing nicely with the if statement  Try this:

```
$handle = opendir('img/gallery/'.$file.'/');
if ($handle) {
```

Would also be good to var_dump out the $file value to make sure it is correct.

Surely you will need to nest the second while loop in the first if you are to iterate over each file in each folder...?

Comment: Thanks! This helped me a million times over!